# Scala application.conf file not loading variable from flink environment

Tags: scala, environment-variables, apache-flink, production-environment, flink-streaming

test-app.conf is

```
App {
    postgres {
        dbHost = ${pg_DbHost}
        dbUser = ${pg_DbUser}
        dbPassword = ${pg_DbPassword}
        dbPort = ${pg_DbPort}
   }
```

at **src/main/resources**
And loading using following code

```
val jobConf = ConfigFactory.load("test-app.conf")
val postgresConf : Config = jobConf.getConfig("App.postgres")
```

I export all variables in the environment on local and it's working fine. 
I deployed jar in Flink environment but that it's not loading variable

I also specify the variable in conf/flink-conf.yaml while building flink. 
I deployed the docker image on the Kubernetes cluster.

What's the way to load variable in conf file from flink environment?

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with flink. It seems like a general scala question. On that note 1) typelevel conf library is case sensitive ```App.Postgres``` won't match ```App.postgres``` 2) you are referring to prod environment but you aren't giving us any insight as to how you are deploying this. Through docker? is it in cluster?

Comment: @sinanspd I konw typelevel conf is case sensitive that was a mistake while posting the question and I also update the question

Comment: are you trying to override argument from environment ? its mentioned in the documentation: https://github.com/lightbend/config , there should not be a problem of doing this, search for java -Dmyapp.foo.bar=10 in documentation

Comment: @Pavel yes and on local it`s working fine but on flink it`s not overriding variables

Comment: Where exactly are you running this code? If it is in the main method, then it will only affect the JVM process in which the client is running. If you want to execute code on the cluster, then you should put it into a UDF.

Comment: @Till Rohrmann this code is written in main and on the local machine it`s working fine but on cluster env, it's not working as expected .

Comment: Yes, because in local execution, the client and the server code is executed in the same JVM. In distributed execution, this is no longer the case. Hence, you only execute the things which are defined in the UDF on the Flink nodes.